# Data transformation Python

Tags: python

the input to my function is a list of lists like the one below, and I want to divide each item in the list after the 3rd one by the third one for each list.. How do I do that?

So far I tried this:

```
def convert_data_percentages(data):

    lst = []

    for x in data:
        lst.append(int(x[2:]) // int(x[2]))
    
    return lst

convert_data_percentages(data, col_id=2)


[["'s-Gravenhage",
  'GM0518',
  '537833',
  '266778',
  '271055',
  '92532',
  '66099',
  '162025',
  '139157',
  '78020',
  '304766',
  '162020',
  '51430',
  '19617'],
 ['Rotterdam',
  'GM0599',
  '644618',
  '317935',
  '326683',
  '103680',
  '86037',
  '197424',
  '159008',
  '98469',
  '367279',
  '187835',
  '62703',
  '26801']]
```

Comment: Create an output list object and then loop through the sub list arguments.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want to divide each item in the list after the 3rd one by the third one for each list."  Do you mean you want to divide the list into groups of three or something else?  Give a sample of the desired output to help clarify.

Comment: I want that every item in the list after the third item in the list so list[2:] is divided by the 3rd item so last[2]. The list should remain the same except for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
data = [["'s-Gravenhage",
  'GM0518',
  '537833',
  '266778',
  '271055',
  '92532',
  '66099',
  '162025',
  '139157',
  '78020',
  '304766',
  '162020',
  '51430',
  '19617'],
 ['Rotterdam',
  'GM0599',
  '644618',
  '317935',
  '326683',
  '103680',
  '86037',
  '197424',
  '159008',
  '98469',
  '367279',
  '187835',
  '62703',
  '26801']]

# reformat original data, dropping first two items and converting to ints
# then extract third item and remaining subset into tuple
subsets = [(lst[:2] + to_int[:1], to_int[0], to_int[1:]) for lst in data if (to_int := [int(i) for i in lst[2:]])]

# walk through tuples generating a new list by dividing all items in the
# remaining subset by the third item
print([first_three + [i / third for i in subset] for first_three, third, subset in subsets])
```

returns:

```
[["'s-Gravenhage", 'GM0518', 537833, 0.4960238587070708, 0.5039761412929292, 0.1720459696597271, 0.1228987436620661, 0.30125522234596985, 0.2587364479308633, 0.14506361640137366, 0.5666554488103185, 0.3012459257799354, 0.09562447823023132, 0.03647414717951483],
['Rotterdam', 'GM0599', 644618, 0.49321458600287305, 0.506785413997127, 0.16083944289486177, 0.13346974487215685, 0.3062651058456326, 0.24667012090881732, 0.15275558547853146, 0.5697622467880202, 0.291389629206755, 0.09727156238268246, 0.04157656162254234]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the only thing is that it should include the first 3 items as before but thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just updated it.